# yeoman grunt build task

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, yeoman

I am using the Compass framework to build my `css` files.
I created a new `.scss` file `test.scss` in `app/styles` separate from `main.scss`.

While using `grunt build`, all of my `.scss` files have been compiled to css and created in the `.tmp` folder, but only `main.css` is moved to `dist/style`. My `test.css` file is not moving.

**Gruntfile:**

```
// Generated on 2014-04-01 using generator-webapp 0.4.7
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

// Load grunt tasks automatically
require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

// Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
require('time-grunt')(grunt);

// Define the configuration for all the tasks
grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: {
        // Configurable paths
        app: 'app',
        dist: 'dist'
    },

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
        js: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['jshint'],
            options: {
                livereload: true
            }
        },
        jstest: {
            files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
            tasks: ['test:watch']
        },
        gruntfile: {
            files: ['Gruntfile.js']
        },
        compass: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
            tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        styles: {
            files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
            },
            files: [
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
                '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,svg,webp}'
            ]
        }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
        options: {
            port: 9000,
            livereload: 35729,
            // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
            hostname: 'localhost'
        },
        livereload: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
        test: {
            options: {
                port: 9001,
                base: [
                    '.tmp',
                    'test',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                ]
            }
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                open: true,
                base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                livereload: false
            }
        }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                dot: true,
                src: [
                    '.tmp',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*',
                    '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
        options: {
            jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
        },
        all: [
            'Gruntfile.js',
            '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*',
            'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
    },


    // Mocha testing framework configuration options
    mocha: {
        all: {
            options: {
                run: true,
                urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
            }
        }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
        options: {
            sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
            generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
            imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
            javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
            fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
            importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components',
            httpImagesPath: '/images',
            httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
            httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
            relativeAssets: false,
            assetCacheBuster: false
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
            }
        },
        server: {
            options: {
                debugInfo: true
            }
        }
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
        options: {
            browsers: ['last 2 version', 'ie 8', 'ie 9']
        },
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
                src: '{,*/}*.css',
                dest: '.tmp/styles/'
            }]
        }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the HTML file
    'bower-install': {
        app: {
            html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
            ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
        }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png,webp}',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*'
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        },
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on rev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        },
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },

    // The following *-min tasks produce minified files in the dist folder
    imagemin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.{gif,jpeg,jpg,png}',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },
    svgmin: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
                src: '{,*/}*.svg',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
            }]
        }
    },
    htmlmin: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeOptionalTags: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true
            },
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: '{,*/}*.html',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
            }]
        }
    },

    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
     cssmin: {
         dist: {
             files: {
                 '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
                     '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                     '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
                 ]
             }
         }
     },
    // uglify: {
    //     dist: {
    //         files: {
    //             '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //                 '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //             ]
    //         }
    //     }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //     dist: {}
    // },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
        dist: {
            files: [{
                expand: true,
                dot: true,
                cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
                dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
                src: [
                    '*.{ico,png,txt}',
                    '.htaccess',
                    'images/{,*/}*.webp',
                    '{,*/}*.html',
                    'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*',
                    'bower_components/' + (this.includeCompass ? 'sass-' : '') + 'bootstrap/' + (this.includeCompass ? 'fonts/' : 'dist/fonts/') +'*.*'
                ]
            }]
        },
        styles: {
            expand: true,
            dot: true,
            cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
            dest: '.tmp/styles/',
            src: '{,*/}*.css'
        }
    },


    // Generates a custom Modernizr build that includes only the tests you
    // reference in your app
    modernizr: {
        devFile: '<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        outputFile: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js',
        files: [
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/vendor/*'
        ],
        uglify: true
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up build process
    concurrent: {
        server: [
            'compass:server',
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        test: [
            'copy:styles'
        ],
        dist: [
            'compass',
            'copy:styles',
            'imagemin',
            'svgmin'
        ]
    }
});


grunt.registerTask('serve', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
        return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'clean:server',
        'concurrent:server',
        'autoprefixer',
        'connect:livereload',
        'watch'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('server', function () {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve']);
});

grunt.registerTask('test', function(target) {
    if (target !== 'watch') {
        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:test',
            'autoprefixer',
        ]);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
        'connect:test',
        'mocha'
    ]);
});

grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'compass:dist',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'copy:dist',
    'modernizr',
    //'rev',
    'usemin'
    //'htmlmin'
]);

grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
]);
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main.css you see in your dist folder is actually a file concatenation.
If you want your test.scss to be in there, look at your index.html file.

You will see the following:

```

```
<!-- build:css({.tmp,app}) styles/main.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/test.css">

<!-- endbuild -->
```

```

When you build, yeoman will look for all those files and create a main.css from them.